# Map is not a function after changing the element in array

Tags: reactjs

I have the next situation:
i have a component in react where i have an array of items like: `data: ['bad', 'good'],`. I used map() to display them:

```js
   

 {data.map(i => {
                return (
                    <Element key={i}>
                        {i.toUpperCase()}
                    </Element>
               );
    })}
```

After that i have a functionality to edit this items on front end (i use a button near each element with edit function). For example if i edit the data `bad` in `bad1`and save this, i display the typeof of `data` in console, and there the type is not array anymore, but string. This is why i get the error: `data.map is not a function`. How to solve this?

Comment: Please include the code for your edit function, too.

Comment: @m.sohail, the code is too long, plus the logic is large in the component, but it works, because when  apply the edit function to change the title for example, after saving all work, but when i try to change an element which i render with map function, the error appears. Also i tried to comment the map function and to render the element not as an array, but as a string, and it works. The issue is appear after saving the changes of an array element the `data` is a string not an array and the app is crushing. Do you have any solutions?

Comment: Without seeing the related part I am not sure if anybody can help you. So, at least try to add the most related parts to your question or even better try to mimic your code and create a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io) if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like at some point your data array is being changed and that is causing the error. Try using `console.log('string')` on your data array in order to debug it and figure out where it is changing and breaking.